# Отправка формы jquery не через submit()

Tags: jquery, submit

Коллеги, такая проблема:

Есть скрипт

```
$('.back-message form').on('submit' , function  (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
alert ('!!!');
$(this).submit();
})
```

По сути, он отлавливает сабмит формы и что-то делает.
После действий надо форму отправить, но `$(this).submit();`  вызывает это же событие, и в итоге мы видим бесконечный алерт.

Как отправить форму из этой функции, чтоб она не вызвала сама себя?

Спасибо!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/   вместо $(this).submit();

Comment: Вариант отправить форму через ajax, в общем-то, тоже подходит. 

А есть ли еще варианты? 
(Ну, то есть  если форму надо будет на другой домен отправить, работа с аяксом усложнится.)

Comment: Ну, можно отлавливать еще нажатие на кнопку, и по ней сабмитить форму...

Comment: @Bo6JI9 По поводу того, чтоб отлавливать клик - можно, но тогда становятся бесполезны атрибуты required и проверка мыла с помощью type='email'

Comment: @volkoff, о как у вас все сложно) Ну можно прикрутить какой-нибудь JQueryValidator...)

Comment: @Bo6JI9,  хотелось найти решение с минимальным количеством телодвижений. 
ТАк что вариант отлавливать сабмит, но отправлять форму аяксом озказался проще :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.back-message form').on('submit' , function  (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Собираем все поля в форме, и отправляем их на урл указанный в атрибуте action формы
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(result) {
        // Тут что-то делаем с ответом сервера.
    });
})
```